# Input array with scanner, now can't print array?

Tags: java, arrays, println

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Create an array, and define its length with user input (scanner). ✓
2. Loop through the array to fill in its values. ✓
3. After defining its length and filling in the values according to the length, printing the whole array. X

I wasn't able to achieve number 3. Can someone help me? I simply need to print the array.

This is my code:

```
package arrayinputoutput;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArrayInputOutput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;
        int[] test;

        System.out.println("How long should the array be?");
        x = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < x + 1; i++) {
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Please fill in position " + i + ":");
            i = input.nextInt();

        }
        //System.out.println(test[]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But you're not filling the array!! As you read each value, you have to fill the array on each index.

Comment: @RenatoAfonso That's not the real problem; this code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @progyammer First of all from what do you assume it doesn't compile? it compiles just FINE.

Comment: Why it doesn't compile? I think it compiles, although it is not doing half of what he says, but it compiles.... :)

Comment: I'm sorry. Your code does compile. The thing is, you have not initialized the array `test`. In this state, if you try to access any index of that array, it would not compile. But you have not used the array (which is what I failed to notice), so no compiler error is produced. My bad. :-p

Answer (score 2):

- after asking the size, yo have to create the `array`, with the size
- you have to store the input in a box of the array `myArray[i] = input.nextInt();` then skip a line
- please use explicit name for `variables`
- stop to `size` and not `size+1` because indexes start to `0`

---

So like this :

```
int size;
int[] myArray;
System.out.println("How long should the array be?");
size = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
myArray= new int[size];                     //<- create array

for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {           // <- '<size' and '<size+1'
    System.out.println("Please fill in position " + i + ":");
    myArray[i] = input.nextInt();           // <- store in a box of the array
    input.nextLine();
}
```

To print the array, several options like :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
```

OR :

```
for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {          
    System.out.println("Value in position " + i + ":" + myArray[i]);       
}
```

Comment: I have to do Size + 1 because, if i input an array length of 5, it will ask only 4. That's why.

Comment: @DenizYildiz sure BUT you start to 0, that's how array works, look here [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.4) if you set size+1 you'll have OutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 0):

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test));

Try using this to print the array.. Hope it works